# SQL - Exclude four-digit-number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL-Server with and simple table on it.

---

```
ID | Code
---+--------
 1 | 1234
 2 | TEST
 3 | 12556
 4 | TEST1
 5 | 5678
 6 | WART
```

I want to exclude all four-digit-number. In my case that would be `1234` and `5678`.

I know I can use ISNUMERIC() tp check if code is numeric.

I also know I can use:

```
SELECT * FROM Codes WHERE code NOT LIKE '____';
```

to check if my value has four digits, but i dont get it how to combine them.

Any suggentions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `not like`:

```
where code not like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Comment: Wow that was an fast answer thank you! Works perfectly fine :)

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you can use '[0-9]{4}'.

Comment: @Asoub - No you can't. SQL Server pattern syntax is quite basic.

Comment: @Martin Smith, oh right, sorry. I didn't even thought about looking at the DBMS. In SQL-Server you have to use something like (`url` NOT REGEXP 'yourRegex') .

Comment: @Asoub - In SQL Server you first need to create a custom CLR function and then use the RegularExpression classes of the CLR. There is no inbuilt syntax.

Comment: @Thanks, didn't knew that ! Sounds a little bit complex for such a basic feature. I seriously need to read more thoroughly ... it was the syntax for mysql I wrote (because the OP on a question mistook both: 29206404) :/